# Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Estou aprendendo a programar automação de teste utilizando o Selenium WebDriver com o Java, mas quando eu executo o mesmo teste no Firefox e no Internet Explorer aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #logoff-button For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Gostaria de saber o motivo do erro?

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
 package br.com.painelmiaedes.ecovec.menu;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Menupainel {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public void Menu(){

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcaoteste = 0;
        int opcaobrowser = 0;


    do{

        System.out.println("**************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("********************     SEJA BEM VINDO AO PAINEL MI TESTE     ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     ********************************      ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     ESCOLHA A OPÇÃO PARA O SEU TESTE      ***********************");
        System.out.println("**************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("********************     OPÇÕES DE TESTE NO LOGIN              ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     1 - LOGIN ESTADO ESPIRITO SANTO       ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     2 - LOGIN REGIONAL NORTE              ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     3 - LOGIN REGIONAL SUL                ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     4 - LOGIN REGIONAL CENTRO             ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     5 - LOGIN REGIONAL METROPOLITANA      ***********************");
        System.out.println("**************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("********************     OPÇÕES DE BROWSER                     ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     1 - GOOGLE CHROME                     ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     2 - MOZILLA FIREFOX                   ***********************");
        System.out.println("********************     3 - INTERNET EXPLORER                 ***********************");
        System.out.println("**************************************************************************************");

        Scanner entradateste = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner entradabrowser = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\n\n Digite a opção de login:");
        opcaoteste = entradateste.nextInt();

        if(opcaoteste == 0){
            System.out.printf("Você escolheu a opcao sair: " + "\n" + "\n" + opcaoteste + " - " + "saindo......" + "\n");   
        }else if(opcaoteste == 1){
            System.out.printf("Você escolheu a opcao de teste de login: " + "\n" + "\n" + opcaoteste + " - " + "Espirito Santo" + "\n");
        }else if(opcaoteste == 2){
            System.out.printf("Você escolheu a opcao de teste de login: " + "\n" + "\n" + opcaoteste + " - " + "Regional Norte" + "\n");
        }else if(opcaoteste == 3){  
            System.out.printf("Você escolheu a opcao de teste de login: " + "\n" + "\n" + opcaoteste + " - " + "Regional Sul" + "\n");
        }else if(opcaoteste == 4){
            System.out.printf("Você escolheu a opcao de teste de login: " + "\n" + "\n" + opcaoteste + " - " + "Regional Centro" + "\n");
        }else if(opcaoteste == 5){
            System.out.printf("Você escolheu a opcao de teste de login: " + "\n" + "\n" + opcaoteste + " - " + "Regional Metropolitana" + "\n");
        }

        switch(opcaoteste){
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("\nDigite o browser para a execucao do teste:");
            opcaobrowser = entradabrowser.nextInt();

            if(opcaobrowser == 1){
                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Google Chrome" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();

            }else if(opcaobrowser == 2){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Mozilla Firefox" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();
            }else if(opcaobrowser == 3){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Internet Explorer" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();         
            }           
            break;

        case 2: 
            System.out.println("\nDigite o browser para a execucao do teste:");
            opcaobrowser = entradabrowser.nextInt();

            if(opcaobrowser == 1){
                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Google Chrome" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();

            }else if(opcaobrowser == 2){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Mozilla Firefox" + "\n");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();
            }else if(opcaobrowser == 3){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Internet Explorer" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();
              }
            break;

        case 3: 
            System.out.println("\nDigite o browser para a execucao do teste:");
            opcaobrowser = entradabrowser.nextInt();

            if(opcaobrowser == 1){
                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Google Chrome" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();

            }else if(opcaobrowser == 2){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Mozilla Firefox" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();
            }else if(opcaobrowser == 3){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Internet Explorer" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();
              }
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("\nDigite o browser para a execucao do teste:");
            opcaobrowser = entradabrowser.nextInt();

            if(opcaobrowser == 1){
                System.out.printf("você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Google Chrome" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();

            }else if(opcaobrowser == 2){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Mozilla Firefox" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();
            }else if(opcaobrowser == 3){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Internet Explorer" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();
              }
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("\nDigite o browser para a execucao do teste:");
            opcaobrowser = entradabrowser.nextInt();

            if(opcaobrowser == 1){
                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Google Chrome" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();

            }else if(opcaobrowser == 2){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Mozilla Firefox" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();
            }else if(opcaobrowser == 3){

                System.out.printf("Você escolheu o Browser:" + opcaobrowser + "-" + "Internet Explorer" + "\n");

                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                driver.get("http://painel.miaedes.com.br");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
                driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("logoff-button")).click();
              }
            break;

            default:    
                System.out.printf("Opção Inválida digite uma outra opção: \n\n");
          }
       }while(opcaoteste !=0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá marcel, o problema está na sua página. certifique que `http://painel.miaedes.com.br` tenha um botão com id `log-off`. Tente repetir menos seu código também. Está bem penoso pra entender o fluxo do teste.

Answer (score 0):

Este problema ocorre pois o selenium eta tentando executar uma ação em um local que ainda não esta carregado. Para que você consiga fazer este teste você vai precisar que o selenium aguarde o navegador carregar para poder fazer a ação.

**Exemplo de clique:**

```
Webdriver wait = new WebdDriverWait(driver,10) // este objeto recebe seu driver e o tempo que deve esperar 


wait.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementClickable(By.id("id do botao"))); //nesta linha ele vai aguardar que seja carregado na tela um botão com o id informado
driver.findElement(By.id("id do botao")).click;//esta linha ele irá clicar no botão após a espera
```

Outro meio de resolver o problema é usando thred porem isto não é uma boa prática.

**Exemplo:**

```
new.thread.sleep(1000) // aqui ele vai aguar dar 1s antes de clicar 
driver.findElement(By.id("id do botao")).click;//esta linha ele irá clicar no botão após a espera
```

Answer (score 0):

Este é um problema de Timeout, como descrito pelo colega. Outra solução seria por **Espera Implícita**.

**Exemplo**

1. Primeiro é necessário fazer a seguinte importação:

   `import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;`
2. No trecho em que deseja que o algoritmo aguarde escreva a seguinte linha de código:

   `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Este método recebe o tempo desejado e unidade de tempo.`

Desta forma o algoritmo aguarda durante um tempo especifico e não por elementos. Pode ser útil em testes que precisam verificar se determinados são elementos são carregados em um tempo específico.